# Odoo - Filter users with specific group in many2one

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am trying to create a drop-down in my custom module form where i want to show users from a specific group

```
fields.Many2one('res.user',string="Admins", domain=[('groups_id','=',12)])
```

this is what i tried, adding a domain but it is not working.

I want to show all user who are admins in this drop-down.

Comment: you have an option in the view called "groups" (e.g. groups="hr_recruitment.group_hr_recruitment_manager"). Is it enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try:

```
fields.Many2one('res.user',string="Admins", domain=[('groups_id','in',[12])])
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Actually it would make no difference if you add it `=` or 'in' criteria. Result would be the same which is `invalid field leaf` because there is no such field in `res.users`

Comment: If you have invalid leaf check the syntax of your domain and by the way groups_id is a many2many field in res.users this answer should work can you post your code that give you this error

Comment: I am getting this error  `raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field u'groups_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'groups_id', u'in', [12]) on _unknown (ctx: )>"` @CherifOdoo can you help ?

Comment: well there was a mistake by myself. Its working perfectly.Thanks a lot both of you

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
fields.Many2many( comodel_name = "res.users", string = "admin",domain=lambda self: [("groups_id", "=", self.env.ref( "module_name.group_id" ).id)])
```

example:

```
fields.Many2many(comodel_name = "res.users",string="Stock Pickers",domain=lambda self: [( "groups_id", "=", self.env.ref( "stock.group_stock_picker" ).id )] )
```

Comment: i have two groups 
bobian.crm_rep and bobian.operations_rep 
and first one inherit second group .
So when i add this domain
```domain = lambda self: [("groups_id", "=", self.env.ref( "bobian.operations_representative_group" ).id)]```
domain list first and second group 
how to filter with group and not inherited one

Comment: i found a solution```domain = lambda self: [("groups_id", "=", self.env.ref("bobian.operations_representative_group").id),("groups_id", "!=", self.env.ref("bobian.crm_representative_group").id)]```